# Request user to change password upon login after account reset in Solaris 10

Tags: solaris-10

How can I request user to change his password upon login after
I reset his account in Solaris 10?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Solaris 10 you can use `passwd -f <username>` command to do this if you are using the files or nisplus repositories.

Manpage **[here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5165/passwd-1.html#scrolltoc)**

```
# passwd -f user2
passwd: password information changed for user2
```

At next login user2 will get this.

```
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
login: user2
Password:
Choose a new password.
New Password:
```

Answer (score 1):

After you reset the password using `passwd` edit the `/etc/shadow` and set the date for the password to 0. The user has to change his password after typing in the current one which you set by using `passwd`.

An example for a password with 0 day durability:

```
cw:o368bqRZm2WW6:0::::::
```

The zero in the third column says that the password never has changed and with normal security policy settings the user will get something like this after login.

```
# ssh cw@someserver
Password: 
Warning: Your password has expired, please change it now.

New Password:
```

Let me know if it worked for you.